# copy a struct array to another (not struct) array in C

Tags: c, arrays

I am trying to copy name array to another array and print it

```
#include <stdio.h>

typedef struct 
{
    char name[100];
    int age;
} data; 

int main() {
    char new_array[100];
    data people[] = {{ "john", 12},{" kate", 15}};
    for(int i =0; i < sizeof(people); i++) {
        new_array[i] = people[i].name;
        printf("%c ", new_array[i]);
    }

    return 0;
}
```

But it gives me an error:

```
error: assignment to ‘char’ from ‘char *’ makes integer from pointer without a cast [-Werror=int-conversion]
     new_array[i] = people[i].name;
                  ^
```

How do I fix this?

Comment: [`strcpy`](https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/strcpy-in-c-cpp/) and [What is a String in C](https://www.codingame.com/playgrounds/14213/how-to-play-with-strings-in-c) may be handy. This has more to do with copying a string (strcpy/strncpy) than copying array contents (memcpy). Also, a semantic name like `person_name` may be more helpful than `new_array`.

Comment: "The C Programming Language" can also be a nice introduction to many basics - it includes many walk-through examples. This (or a similar) book is often assigned for courses.

Comment: [C11 Standard - 6.3.2.1 Other Operands - Lvalues, arrays, and function designators(p3)](http://port70.net/~nsz/c/c11/n1570.html#6.3.2.1p3) "... an expression that has type *"array of type"* is converted to an expression with type *"pointer to type"* that points to the initial element of the array object and is ***not an lvalue***.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can change:

```
char new_array[100];
```

to:

```
char new_array[10][100]; // for maximum 10 strings
```

Then using `strcpy` to copy string in c. If you want to calculate the number of elements of array, using:

```
sizeof(people)/sizeof(people[0]);
```

Then, the for loop becomes:

```
for(int i =0; i < sizeof(people)/sizeof(people[0]); i++) {
        strcpy(new_array[i],people[i].name);
        printf("%s ", new_array[i]);
}
```

Comment: you can also using `char **` pointer, then allocate it using malloc if you do not want to use array..

Comment: it's better to use `strncpy` instead of `strcpy`

Comment: why `strncpy` is better ?

Comment: `strcpy` is fine if you can guarantee the source is NULL-terminated and fits within the destination.

Answer (score 2):

You are trying to assign a *string*  to a *char* which is described by your error. To copy a string to a char array, you should use `strcpy()`.

Also, your `new_array` is a mere array of characters and has no way to differentiate two different names.

To make it an array of strings, you should use a 2D array where you can index the row to get different strings like below

```
char new_array[10][100]
```

This makes an array of 10 strings of 100 characters each.

Also, your iteration over the array of structure is messy.

To get correct size of array of structure, you should use

```
int size = sizeof(people)/sizeof(people[0])
```

So, your final code becomes-

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>

typedef struct 
{
    char name[100];
    int age;
} data; 

int main() {
    char new_array[10][100];
    data people[] = {{ "john", 12},{" kate", 15}};
    for(int i =0; i < sizeof(people)/sizeof(people[0]); i++) {
        strcpy(new_array[i],people[i].name);
        printf("%s ", new_array[i]);
    }

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: `trying to assign a string literal to a char ` it's not problem

Comment: `new_char[i]` is a single character having size = sizeof(char), "john" is a string literal with size = 5*sizeof(char), 4 for each character j,o,h,n and '\0'. String literals are of type char *. Assigning char * to a single character is the problem here. How can you assign 4 characters to a single character? This is the problem. Read String literal here https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/cpp/c-language/c-string-literals?view=vs-2019.  Correct me if I am wrong.

Comment: when you declare in struct `char name[100]`, it is an array of characters. So you can modify the value in this array. It becomes problem if in struct, the OP use `char * name`

Comment: Aaghh!! Missed that declaration and gone with the initialization... I will update in my answer as well.

Comment: OT, `new_array[10][20]` should be `new_array[10][100]` because the size of `name` in struct is `100`.